# Bootstrap typehead not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

In the code below I'm using Bootstrap typeahead for populate country. I'm initializing typeahead in jQuery but values not get in the textbox. If I remove ng-repeat it works perfectly

```
<div ng-repeat='item in array'>
    <input class="typeahead" type="text" id="Text23" ng-model="dtl.InstCn" ng-required="true" placeholder="Country">
</div>
<script>
    $('.typeahead').typeahead({source: sourceArr});
</script>
```

How do I use typehead with ng-repeat?

Comment: are you on **bootstrap 3** version ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a plunker? I can't understand the sense of ng-repeat in your code snippet. You aren't using anything from the ng-repeat.

Otherwise try this using UI Bootstrap (Bootstrap components written in pure AngularJS) from AngularUI:

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead